# Output a simple json file to a rest api with golang

Tags: json, rest, go

This is my first go project.  All I want to do is read a file.json on my server, then make it available to others via a REST API. But I'm getting errors.  Here's what I have so far.

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "io/ioutil"
    "fmt"
)

func GetDetail(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    b,_ := ioutil.ReadFile("file.json");

    rawIn := json.RawMessage(string(b))
    var objmap map[string]*json.RawMessage
    err := json.Unmarshal(rawIn, &objmap)
    if err != nil {
      fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(objmap)

    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(objmap)
}

func main() {
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    router.HandleFunc("/detail", GetDetail).Methods("GET")

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8000", router))
}
```

file.json

```
{
  favourite_color:"blue",
  attribute:{density:23,allergy:"peanuts",locations:["USA","Canada","Jamaica"]},
  manufacture_year:1998
}
```

When I run `go build; ./sampleproject`, then go to my web browser at `http://localhost:8000/detail`, I get the error message:

> invalid character 'f' looking for beginning of object key string
>   map[]

I've tried a few marshal methods, but they all give me different errors.  I just need a working example to study from to better understand how all this works.

I should also mention that file.json does not have a fixed schema.  It can change drastically at any minute to have a random set of data.

How do I get around the error invalid character f message and get my file.json to render at `http://localhost:8000/detail`?

Comment: The file is not valid JSON because the object member names are not quoted strings.  Also, you can simply copy the file to the response. There's no need decode / encode.

Comment: awesome, putting quotes around all the keys in the file.json did the job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As cerise mentioned, it's just formatting error in the JSON file.  Must quote all properties.

Then the rest of the code works